# With LIMIT, how do you check if there are any nodes left?

Tags: neo4j

I am implementing cursor-based pagination which has a `hasNextPage`, so if a query has something like `LIMIT 20`, how would you return the boolean whether there are still more nodes remaining which fit the MATCH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a `LIMIT 21` but only return the first 20; the presence of a 21st element determines `hasNextPage`.

Comment: The best solution to this problem has ever seen! :)